# Cocos2d 2.x: is there a way to achieve z layering across multiple sprite sheets?

Tags: ios, optimization, cocos2d-iphone, layer

I have 2 sprite sheets, **one for the characters and HUD layer** and **one for the background**. The "background sprite sheet" **has an actual background part and a "foreground part"** which **should be layered in a z level above the characters**.

Here comes the problem. Using CCSpriteBatchNode in order to optimize drawing performance I am forced to have two different CCSpriteBatchNodes of size 2048*2048 each in order to use the 2 sprite sheets.

Here is a brief "schematization" of the structure I would like to achieve:

```
z=0  background    sheetBackground 
z=1  characters    sheetCharacters
z=2  foreground    sheetBackground
sheetBackground -> spriteBatchNodeA
sheetCharacters -> spriteBatchNodeB

!!! Conflict ->  sprites in a spriteBatchNode cannot be z-ordered in respect to sprites in another batch node !!
```

**Unfortunately the z ordering of the sprites affects only the sprites within the same CCSpriteBatchNode and not the "global z order".**

To overcome this problem the only way to me would be to have a sprite sheet of double size (4096*4096). I have found this github project [CCBigImage](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCBigImage) that supports bigger files. **Before I start changing my code structure I wanted to ask you if this would this be an accaptable solution or if there are other ways to achieve this.**

Comment: FYI not all devices support 4kx4k textures. The only way to achieve flexible z sorting is enabling z-buffering and using vertexz.

Comment: Are you sure you need this optimisation? You might be making it harder on yourself by trying to put them in a batch node when simply creating the sprite from a sprite frame is all you need. Batch nodes really only make a massive difference when you are creating lots of the same sprite.

Comment: @BenTrengrove I did not know this, I feel the real need to talk to some experienced developer like you to have a general grasp of those optimization things. I have spent 10 months learning Cocos2D and developing my first commercial game but I still "fail" to understand those basic things. It is a sign that I am approaching my work in the wrong way.

Comment: This post is good. Should explain some things. http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/#more-3365